# How stage work in Libgdx?

Tags: java, button, libgdx, actor, stage

I'm new to stage class and actors, I know that a button is an actor so I created one:

```
public void create(){
    buttonAtlas=new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("buttons/button.pack"));
    skin=new Skin();
    skin.addRegions(buttonAtlas);
    buttonStyle=new Button.ButtonStyle();
    buttonStyle.up=skin.getDrawable("animation00");
    buttonStyle.down=skin.getDrawable("animation01");

    button=new Button(buttonStyle);
    button.setPosition(200,700);

    stage=new Stage();
    stage.addActor(button); //the problem is that nothing happens.
}
```

It would be really helpful if you can explain what is a stage and actors.

Comment: Did you read the [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d)? If it's not clear enough, please ask a more specific question,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LibGDX an `Actor` is a representation of a 2D Node Graph Object.

The actor will have a list of actions, and contains parameters such as position, rectangular size, origin, scale, rotation, Z index, and color.

You're `Actors` are basically the fundamental objects you're going to be applying `Actions` to thorough-out the progress of the scene on the `Stage`.

---

Meanwhile a `Stage` can be thought of just like the real world stage. On the `Stage` you will have `Actors`. The `Stage` can also handle input events and is comparable to hierarchical view of all active `Actors` and their current in-progress `Actions`.

A good place to read more would be the nightly Javadocs. They can be found [here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/).

The specific JavaDocs do a really good job of describing the Actors and Stage.